# TypeError: fetch is not a function, What did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I'm trying to use `node-fetch` in order to fetch this website that has this JSON file where I can use it for my discord bot.

Code (JS):

```js
const fetch = import("node-fetch")

// some code until

data = ""
        try {
            data = await fetch(`http://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/${subreddit.toLowerCase()})}`).then(res => res.json)
            errored = false
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
```

It errors saying:

```
TypeError: fetch is not a function
```

How do I fix this?

FYI, Using require() resulted in an error as such:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
              ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module F:\Users\Basil Atif\Folders\VsauceBot\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js from F:\Users\Basil Atif\Folders\VsauceBot\src\Commands\reddit.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in F:\Users\Basil Atif\Folders\VsauceBot\src\Commands\reddit.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.    
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Comment: You're mixing up import and require. Dynamic import is _asynchronous_, so what you've named `fetch` is a promise object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, I tried to use require() and it ended up erroring, in the error it said to use a dynamic import. What do I do?

Comment: Your context and original error aren't clear. If you're using dynamic import, fetch is what the promise _resolves_ to.

Comment: @Baselistic See the documentation for the correct use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#common-usage

Comment: FYI it looks like your personal info is included in the file path in the error stack trace at the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

Try using this style of import:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

Comment: It errors saying I cannot use import outside of a module.

Comment: Try adding “type”:“module” to your package.json

Comment: Causes a lot of chaos, Everything that used require() now needs import (a lot), a new error popped up saying that .json is not a valid file extension, Sorry for being stupid.

Comment: Can you share your package.json please?

Comment: Instead of editing the package.json you can add type="module" to the javascript file, that you would like to use, like this: ```<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>```

Comment: @Baselistic, have you found any solution?

Comment: I used Axios instead. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: I got an error stating `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement inside the Node.js REPL, alternatively use dynamic import`. So `node-fetch` is no longer available in the interactive shell?

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

```
let get=document.getElementById("get");
let **fetch**=document.getElementById("fetch"); //this var create problem
let content=document.getElementById("content");


function getData(){

    
    let url= "https://api.github.com/users/github";
    fetch(url).then(
        (res)=>{
        return res.text();
    }).then((data)=>{
    content.innerHTML = data;
    });

}
getData()
```

**output:**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUfGG.png)

**Solution:**

```
let get=document.getElementById("get");
let **fet**=document.getElementById("fetch");// change the name of the variable
let content=document.getElementById("content");


function getData(){

    
    let url= "https://api.github.com/users/github";
    fetch(url).then(
        (res)=>{
        return res.text();
    }).then((data)=>{
    content.innerHTML = data;
    });

}
getData()
```

**output:**
[now the data is fetched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OGaK.png)

Comment: change the name of the variable fetch